# What sample size is necessary to jackknife estimate variance of large dataset?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, jackknife

So I'm working on a project and I wrote a java library that I can use to perform feature ranking and  Naive Bayes classification on data sets. I wrote and tested the library on small data sets so I know that it does the math correctly as far as using bayes rule and calculating entropy, etc.

However, the data set that I actually want to use the library on is pretty large, or at least larger than anything that I've ever worked with. My training data has 660,000 entries each with 72 different features.  I thought that I could write a class that I can use to sample my training data instead of using the entire 660,000 entry data set to make my calculations.

I went back to one of my undergrad books and looked up how to calculate how large of a sample size I need, but I need to know the standard deviation before hand. I know that I can use Jackknife resampling to estimate the variance and from there I can estimate the standard deviation, but how to I determine how large of a sample I need in order to perform my Jackknife?

Using N-1 is going to take just as long as using the entire data set and this is the problem that I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: I edited your title to bring it closer to the content of your question. Please feel free to change or roll back if I've erred.

Comment: @SeanEaster Do you know the answer to my question? Why would I need the entropy? I need the Standard deviation to calculate the sample size. I'm up for using a different technique though if you can explain it.

Comment: Ah, it seems I confused your title with the body of your question. For clarity, you'd like to know what sample size is necessary to jackknife estimate standard error, is that right? I have no answer to that at hand, but an accurate title could help draw others' attention.